# iOS 7 adding UIView to UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I am trying to add a UIView to UITableView in iOS 7 to display and "Not Results" view.

My code works fine in iOS 6, but getting white page in iOS 7.

```
    [self.tableView insertSubview:_nomatchesView belowSubview:self.tableView];
```

Anyone run into this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: How can you make a view insert a subview below itself? That doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because I was setting shadowColor on the label.

> matchesLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor lightTextColor];

I removed that line it corrected the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.size.height/2, self.tableView.frame.size.width/2,125, 125)];
    label.center = self.tableView.center;
    label.text = @"No Results"
    [self.tableView addSubview:label];
    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

This is tested and works in iOS 7

Comment: @TimWalsh Instead of editing your solution to your question you should write it up for an answer and give it a check.